# Is it good practice to replace Class with Class<? extends Object> to avoid warnings?

Tags: java, generics, warnings, raw-types

In a bunch o' places in my code, I have something like this:

```
public Class mySpecialMethod() {
  return MySpecialClass.class;
}
```

which causes the warning

> Class is a raw type. References to
>   generic type Class should be
>   parameterized.

But, if I replace

`Class`

with

`Class<? extends Object>`

the warning goes away.

Is this simple practice ok, or could it cause trouble later?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's the correct thing to do only if there really is no common base class or interface that the Class object needs to represent.

Also `Class<?>` is effectively the same as `Class<? extends Object>`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's totally right.

It's a requirement that you specify the type. And if you can't, you have to specify the wildcard.

Further reading: [Java Language Specification: Parameterized Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.5.1)

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you can be even more precise :

```
public Class<MySpecialClass> mySpecialMethod() {
  return MySpecialClass.class;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not really a Java programmer here, but read some good papers about generics.

Yes, you should add some wildcard or the exact type (`Class<MySpecialClass>`) to add safety. The reason is that Class is a generic. So, `Class<Bar>` and `Class<Foo>` are the same after erasure of their generic type parameter. They all become `Class`, the so-called raw type. That erasure happens when compiling. Some example to illustrate this where the compiler helps you with automatic casting (exception handling omitted for brevity):

```
class Mine { }

class Vara {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        { // works. translated to Mine m = (Mine) c.newInstance();
            Class<Mine> c = Mine.class;
            Mine m = c.newInstance();
        }
        { // doesn't work. need a cast: Mine m = (Mine) c.newInstance();
            Class c = Mine.class; // also Class<?> or Class<? extends Object>
            Object o = c.newInstance(); // but this works. pointing to a Mine
            Mine m = (Mine) c.newInstance(); // needs a manual cast
        }
    }
}
```

Saying `Class<?>` (and the equivalent `Class<? extends Object>`), you tell the compiler you really wanted a Class whose `T` is Object, and didn't accidentally used the raw type. But it won't add any convenience casts. All that generics do is to insert automatic casts for you, to cast from `Object` to the destination type. Generics are the same whether used with type U or with type T at runtime for compatibility reasons with older java versions.